# Getting authentication error "Unable to find credentials in request" when I make a POST request in Cypress automation

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm making a POST request in cypress automation but I keep getting an authentication error. The endpoint takes basic authetication.

```
  "error": "AuthenticationError",
  "text": "Unable to find credentials in request". 

Here is my request:
 
 cy.request({
                    url: 'TEST ENDPOINT',
                    method : 'POST',
                    auth: { 
                        username: 'test@test.com', 
                        password: 'test1'
                    }, 

                  body: {
                        
                        "firstname": "Bruce",
                        "lastname": "lee"
                 
                    });
 
          });
```

When I hit the same endpoint in POSTMAN it works as expected. Not sure what's wrong with my request.

Comment: How are you passing your credentials and what kind of authentication method are you using in POSTMAN ?

Comment: The authentication method is Basic Authentication, which takes username and password. In Postman I'm passing credentials under the Authorization tab and type set to basic authorization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no key called "auth", you should use either Header to pass your token or auth key in it.

```
method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Bearer '+token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
```

Comment: Yes there is: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Arguments

Comment: oh first time i am hearing it. then compare your postman console payload and cypress (F12) network api payload. you will find the difference